# How do I know which tile on a grid an element is?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a pesudo-snake game to test my abilites. I have a grid of 25 on 25 in my webpage, and a square that the player controls on the grid and needs to get to the food. The player starts on the top left tile (tile 1, 1) and I want to know what tile he is on each move he takes - for example, if he goes down from the starting tile (tile 1, 1), I want for example a console.log that says (1,2) and then if he goes to the right it says (2, 2). Is it possible to do this or not? Thanks in advance!

Here is in a nutshell the type of code I want:

```
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
    const key = event.key;
    if (key == "ArrowRight") {
        console.log(*Here I want it to say which tile the player is*);
    } else if (key == "ArrowLeft") {
        console.log(*Here I want it to say which tile the player is*);
    } else if (key == "ArrowDown") {
        console.log(*Here I want it to say which tile the player is*);
    } else if (key == "ArrowUp") {
        console.log(*Here I want it to say which tile the player is*);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code that you use to draw the 25x25 grid and how you store your tiles? You will probably need a 2 dimensional array for this.

Comment: I didn't do anything fancy, I did:                                                                                           `                                                                        
    #game {
    background-color: black;
    margin: 50px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(25, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(25, 1fr);
}                                                                                                                                      '

Comment: You need to save the state of the snake. Whenever a key is pressed, you can then get it from a global object that saves its state. The function that takes care of key triggers, should not care where the snake is, just to get current state and order something else to do something with the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out which key the user presses using simple javascript as below -

```js
// start_pos - 0th index denotes x-axis , 1st index denotes y-axis. User starts at (0,0)
let start_pos = [0, 0]

document.onkeydown = function(event) {
  const key = event.key;
  switch (event.key) {
    case "ArrowLeft":
      start_pos[0] -= 1
      console.log(start_pos)
      break;
    case "ArrowRight":
      start_pos[0] += 1
      console.log(start_pos)
      break;
    case "ArrowUp":
      start_pos[1] += 1
      console.log(start_pos)
      break;
    case "ArrowDown":
      start_pos[0] -= 1
      console.log(start_pos)
      break;
  }

};
```

Now, according to the key he presses, you can calculate the current position from the last position and pressed key. This is what I am doing in the switch case ladder. You can apply similar logic in your code as well. You would need to keep a variable that stores the state of position the user is currently.